# How can i create an Array of textBox in c++ with a NET framework?

Tags: arrays, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm developing Wordle in C++ and I'm using the NET graphic framework, I have created 30 textBoxes with the drag and drop interface but in order to make my program work I need to put them in a container, such as an array, what should I use to create it?

Answer (score 1):

Try as shown below.
Details as comments.

```
//DECLARE SOME TEXTBOXES
TextBox^ textBox1 = gcnew TextBox();
textBox1->Text = "TextBox1";

TextBox^ textBox2 = gcnew TextBox();
textBox2->Text = "TextBox2";

TextBox^ textBox3 = gcnew TextBox();
textBox3->Text = "TextBox3";

//DECLARE AN ARRAY FOR HOLDING TEXTBOXES
array<TextBox^>^ arrayOfTextBoxes = gcnew array<TextBox^>(3);

arrayOfTextBoxes[0] = textBox1;
arrayOfTextBoxes[1] = textBox2;
arrayOfTextBoxes[2] = textBox3;

//TEST
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     Console::WriteLine(arrayOfTextBoxes[i]->Text);
```